# Sisters and brothers and a mother have I but a father I have not

Tags: knowledge

I have sisters and brothers and a mother - but I have no father.  What am I?

My brothers also do not have a father

My sisters do have a father

Comment: I believe the hints here should be part of the question proper. As criteria for the solution they are essential to solving the puzzle, otherwise there would be too many possible answers and ambiguities.

Comment: Fair enough - edited.

Comment: You're Luke Skywalker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you be a

> male honey bee?  I'm a little fuzzy on the biology, but I understand that with honey bees, the males hatch from unfertilised eggs, while the females of the species come from fertilised eggs.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, so people who don't know the relevant biology can understand?

Comment: Good job - I guess it was too easy :)

Comment: @Mike Sorry for the sloppy answer - I've added some explanation now.

Comment: @Tracy I just got lucky - was teaching my class about the Fibonacci sequence a short while ago, and learnt that because of this fact, the family trees of these beings grow (upwards) according to the Fibonacci sequence.  Isn't Nature grand?